# sending array to PHP via $.post issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have an issue when sending to server array in POST via ajax with JQuery version is `1.10.2`. My array is array of objects (such object is basically an associative array).

Function `JSON.stringify(word_mean_arr);` return `[[]]` - so it fail to work and if I simply write:

```
$.post( "./ajax2/myscript.php", {block_id: bl_id, wm_arr: word_mean_arr})
```

I cannot get value of $POST['wm_arr'] like it does not exist.

Example of my array is something like:

```
[[key]=>1,[value]=>"this_is_"],[[key]=>2,[value]=>"this_is_str2"]
```

So my object is:

```
[  [key]=>1,   [value]=>"this_is_str"]
```

This is how I form my array

```
var word_mean_arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i <= this.n_of_wd_mean; i++)
{
    var temp_arr = new Array();
    temp_arr['key'] = $("#tswes_2_"+i).val();
    temp_arr['value'] = $("#tswes_2_"+i).val();
    word_mean_arr.push(temp_arr);
}
console.log("Array to server length>" + word_mean_arr.length);
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(word_mean_arr);
```

How should I transfer data and what is the problem?

**UPDATE 1:** `JSON.stringify(temp_arr)` is `[]`, but when `console.log(word_mean_arr)` I see whole structure of my array.

**UPDATE 2:** Replacing `temp_arr['key']` with `temp_arr[0]`, solves my problem. But still qurious how to send key->val.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your temp_arr variable is initialized as an array, but then you work with it as with an object, accessing keys that it does not have.

This will solve the problem:

```
var temp_arr = {
    key: $("#tswes_2_"+i).val(),
    value: $("#tswes_2_"+i).val()
};
```

instead of this:

```
var temp_arr = new Array();
temp_arr['key'] = $("#tswes_2_"+i).val();
temp_arr['value'] = $("#tswes_2_"+i).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't use `JSON.stringify`, jQuery does encode the variables itself when using `$.post`.

```
var word_mean_arr = $('.tswes').serialize();
console.debug('sending: ');
console.debug(word_mean_arr);
$.post('./ajax2/myscript.php', { block_id: bl_id, wm_arr: word_mean_arr });
```

If it does not work, try different:

```
var word_mean_arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= this.n_of_wd_mean; i++)
{
    var temp_arr   = {};
    temp_arr.key   = $("#tswes_2_"+i).val();
    temp_arr.value = $("#tswes_2_"+i).val();
```